# Calculation in code

Tags: c, math, wait

Can someone please tell me what does this line of code do?

```
wait = (20ul*50ul)-1ul ;
```

I understand the mathematics that is carried out which is the product of 20 and 50 then subtract 1 from it but I dont understand the ul part. Is it just a unit or does it have any significance.
Thank you

Comment: "Can someone please tell me what does this line of code do?" It throws a compilation error as `ẇait` is a standard C library function - and assigning to non-pointer functions is prohibited.

Comment: @H2CO3: `wait` is not a standard C library function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah :) At least it's part of POSIX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ul is a notational shorthand for Unsigned Long.

Comment: And at least the 'l' should be written in upper case, to avoid confusion with '1'.

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` suffix forces each constant expression to be type `unsigned long`.

Normally, the type of an integer constant expression is the first type in which its value can be represented.  Without the suffix, each of the literal expressions `20`, `50`, and `1` would be type `int` instead of `unsigned long`.

For *this particular calculation* it doesn't really matter, but there are times when you do want to force unsigned operations on constant expressions (overflow on unsigned operations is well-defined).